# how to detect parameter of a method is null in php?

Tags: php

I want to detect parameters of a method is null or not in php.
I use ReflectionParameter but it has strange behavior for detecting the type of parameter. Here's code I tested:

```
 class myClass{

        public function test($param2=null,$param1,$param3='something'){
                echo  "it's $param1";

                if(!is_null($param2)){
                    echo "<br> it's $param2";
                }
        }

        public function reflection(){
            $reflection = new ReflectionMethod($this,'test');
            $params = $reflection->getParameters();

            echo '<pre> public function test($param2=null,$param1,$param3=\'something\'){}
            <hr>';
            #var_dump($params);
            #echo '<hr>';
            $this->reflection_parameter(0);
            echo '<hr>';
            $this->reflection_parameter(1);
            echo '<hr>';
            $this->reflection_parameter(2);
        }

        public function reflection_parameter($position){
            $p = new ReflectionParameter(array($this,'test'),$position);
            #var_dump($p->getPosition(),$p->getName(),$p->getDeclaringFunction());
            var_dump('allowsNull()',$p->allowsNull());
            var_dump('isOptional()',$p->isOptional());
            #var_dump('isArray()',$p->isArray());
            #var_dump('isCallable()',$p->isCallable());
            var_dump('isDefaultValueAvailable()',$p->isDefaultValueAvailable());
            #var_dump('getDefaultValue()',$p->getDefaultValue());
            #var_dump('class',$p->getDeclaringClass()->name);
        }

 }

 $refl= new myClass();
 $refl->reflection();
```

I attached a screenshot of output:
 http://axgig.com/images/21110184497178611107.png

as you can see

```
public function test($param2=null,$param1,$param3='something')
```

param2 can be null but both of isOptional and isDefaultValueAvailable are false same as param1 that doesn't have any default value but for param3 it returns true

Now change first line of test function to:

```
public function test($param1,$param2=null,$param3='something')
```

and see output:
http://axgig.com/images/85816853742428271329.png
now isOptional and isDefaultValueAvailable are true for param2 while it false for previous usage

Comment: I'm not really having any thouhgts about your reflection issue, but be aware that as far as I know this point from the manual should still be heeded: `Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected. `  . Not sure if it fixes your issue though, but take care with those values ;) http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: you cannot without parsing the raw php file yourself.

Yes. This is normal as you cannot omit a parameter in PHP when calling a function. All parameters until the last parameter which doesn't have a default aren't optional and their eventual default values are ignored.

Comment: what about isDefaultValueAvailable ?

Comment: @minttux _their eventual default values are ignored_: means that there won't be any default value available for these first parameters.

Comment: so there is no way to detect parameters has default value or not?

Comment: @minttux yes. (what makes also sense)

Comment: have look at token_get_all if you really need to. but with reflection it isn't possible.

Comment: token_get_all seems very wired way if obey this rule that put each required parameters on right side and not required parameters on left side then can i use ReflectionParameter? for example function myFunc(param1,param2,param3=null,param4='something')